# Calendar current week in color

Tags: color, datetime2, tikz-calendar

I want to display for each week a page containing the number of the week in the year, the date of Monday and that of Saturday in numerical form and a calendar of the current month on which the current week is red.

**Question** :

I achieve this if the dates for 'between' are in clear but not if I use the stored dates.

**Code** :

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,french]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{ext.calendar-plus}
 \usepackage[useregional,showdow,calc,datesep=-]{datetime2}

\usepackage{ifthen}  % fo whiledo 

\begin{document}


% Start date 
\DTMsavedate{dateCourante}{2023-01-16}
\newcount\julianCourant
\DTMsaveddatetojulianday{dateCourante}{\julianCourant}

% final date
\DTMsavedate{dateFinale}{2023-02-12}
\newcount\julianFinale
\DTMsaveddatetojulianday{dateFinale}{\julianFinale}

\newcount\semaineCourante
\newcount\lundi
\newcount\samedi
\newcommand{\anneeEnCours}{2023}

% Next day 
\newcommand{\jourSuivant}{%
    \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{dateCourante}{1}\julianCourant
    \DTMsavejulianday{dateCourante}{\number\julianCourant}
}

% julian day to date  
\newcommand{\dateNumerique}[1]{
    \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{#1}{\myyear}{\mymonth}{\myday}
    \edef\isodate{\myyear-\mymonth-\myday} \myyear-\mymonth-\myday
}

% Every  page  with week number, Monday Saturday dates numeric 
% 
\whiledo{\number\julianCourant < \number\julianFinale }
{%          
    % Compute week number ( ie \semaineCourante )   
    \pgfcalendarjulianyeartoweek
    {\julianCourant}
    {\anneeEnCours}
    {\semaineCourante}

    % Save monday date in julian day ( ie \lundi)   
    \lundi \number\julianCourant\relax
    \jourSuivant \jourSuivant \jourSuivant \jourSuivant \jourSuivant \jourSuivant
    % Pass six days and save saturday           
    \samedi   \number\julianCourant\relax
    \jourSuivant

    % Display week, dates 
    Semaine     \the\semaineCourante ;  Lundi  : \dateNumerique{\lundi} ; samedi : \dateNumerique{\samedi}

    % Try   display one month calendar pn a page, with  red current week            
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,transform shape, every calendar/.style={
                    week list,
                    /tikz/week label left,
                    every week/.append  style={gray!50!black,font=\sffamily},
                    month label above centered,
                    month text= \bfseries\textcolor{red}{\%mt} \%y0,
                    if={(Sunday) [black!50]},
                }]

        \calendar
        [dates=2023-\DTMfetchmonth{dateCourante}-01 to 2023-\DTMfetchmonth{dateCourante}-last]
        % Ok with explicite data                                
        if (between=2023-01-23 { } and  2023-01-28 ) [red] ;
        % Nok with saved dates           (uncomment next line )                 
        %           if (between=\dateNumerique{\lundi} { } and \dateNumerique{\dimanche[red] ; 
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \noindent\rule{0.3\textwidth}{.5pt} Newpage  \rule{0.3\textwidth}{.4pt}  \newline
}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for advance to the genie in the lantern?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

`\dateNumerique` needs to return just `yyyy-mm-dd`, you can't do any calculations in there.

Furthermore `\dimanche` isn't defined (and there's a typo, missing `})`).

---

We can create a `between julians` test that tests two dates against the current julian date (instead of `year-month-day`):

```
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/calendar/between julians/.code 2 args={%
    \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatejulian<#1\relax
    \else
      \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatejulian>#2\relax
      \else
        \pgfcalendarmatchestrue
      \fi
    \fi
  }
}
```

Since there's no `<=` or `>=` in `\ifnum` I'm using the opposite, i.e. if the date isn't less than `#1` and if it isn't greater than `#2` then it must be between `#1` and `#2`.

Then you can use `\lundi` and `\samedi` directly:

```
if (between julians={\lundi}{\numexpr\samedi-1})[red];
```

Since `\dimanche` isn't defined but `\samedi` is, I'll just substract `1` from `\samedi` to get to the Saturday.

The following would work, too:

```
if (and={not=Sunday, between julians={\lundi}{\samedi}})[red];
```

to exclude the Sunday.

Since you already have the week in `\semaineCourante` you could do also

```
 if (and={not=Sunday, week=\semaineCourante}) [red];
```

if I fix a small, stupid bug in the `week` test.

---

I've removed a few spurious spaces in the code.

If you want french spacing around punctuation like `:` and `;` load

```
\usepackage{babel} % option [french] inherited from document class
```

which deals with that much better and automatic.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,french]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.calendar-plus}
\usepackage[useregional,showdow,calc,datesep=-]{datetime2}
\usepackage{ifthen}  % fo whiledo 
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/calendar/between julians/.code 2 args={%
    \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatejulian<#1\relax
    \else
      \ifnum\pgfcalendarifdatejulian>#2\relax
      \else
        \pgfcalendarmatchestrue
      \fi
    \fi
  },
  /pgf/calendar/week/.code={% bug fix ☹
    \ifnum#1=\pgfcalendarifdateweek\relax\pgfcalendarmatchestrue\fi}}
\begin{document}

% Start date 
\DTMsavedate{dateCourante}{2023-01-16}
\newcount\julianCourant
\DTMsaveddatetojulianday{dateCourante}{\julianCourant}

% final date
\DTMsavedate{dateFinale}{2023-02-12}
\newcount\julianFinale
\DTMsaveddatetojulianday{dateFinale}{\julianFinale}

\newcount\semaineCourante
\newcount\lundi
\newcount\samedi
\newcommand{\anneeEnCours}{2023}

% Next day 
\newcommand{\jourSuivant}{%
    \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{dateCourante}{1}\julianCourant
    \DTMsavejulianday{dateCourante}{\number\julianCourant}%
}

% julian day to date  
\newcommand{\dateNumerique}[1]{%
    \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{#1}{\myyear}{\mymonth}{\myday}%
    \edef\isodate{\myyear-\mymonth-\myday}\myyear-\mymonth-\myday
}

% Every  page  with week number, Monday Saturday dates numeric 
% 
\whiledo{\number\julianCourant < \number\julianFinale }
{%
  % Compute week number ( ie \semaineCourante )
  \pgfcalendarjulianyeartoweek
  {\julianCourant}
  {\anneeEnCours}
  {\semaineCourante}%
%
  % Save monday date in julian day ( ie \lundi)   
  \lundi=\julianCourant\relax
  \jourSuivant \jourSuivant \jourSuivant \jourSuivant \jourSuivant \jourSuivant
  % Pass six days and save saturday           
  \samedi   \number\julianCourant\relax
  \jourSuivant

  % Display week, dates 
  Semaine \the\semaineCourante; Lundi: \dateNumerique{\lundi}; samedi: \dateNumerique{\samedi}

  % Try display one month calendar on a page, with red current week
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every calendar/.style={
      week list,
      /tikz/week label left,
      every week/.append  style={gray!50!black,font=\sffamily},
      month label above centered,
      month text= \bfseries\textcolor{red}{\%mt} \%y0,
      if={(Sunday) [black!50]}}]

    \calendar
      [dates=2023-\DTMfetchmonth{dateCourante}-01 to 2023-\DTMfetchmonth{dateCourante}-last]
%     if (between julians={\lundi}{\numexpr\samedi-1})[red]
%     if (and={not=Sunday, between julians={\lundi}{\samedi}})[red];
     if (and={not=Sunday, week=\semaineCourante}) [red];
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \noindent\rule{0.3\textwidth}{.5pt} Newpage \rule{0.3\textwidth}{.4pt} \newline
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this could have been done without `datetime2` but I don't know that package and it may provide a better interface to some things than PGFCalendar.